# Can "Yo" be used to end a conversation?

Tags: slang

I understand "yo" is meant to be used as hello or for emphasizing something. But lets say in a situation where I am texting with someone and at the end of that conversation using "yo" instead of "ok" is correct. Lets take this text for instance.

> Me : Yo
>
> Roommate : sup
>
> Me: The internet ain't working.
>
> Roommate : Yeah I got the email. I will recharge it later.
>
> Me: Thanks dude.
>
> Roommate : Yo.

In this situation, the roommate is using "yo" for saying "yeah kool, bye".

Can yo be used like that or its just wrong to use "yo" to end a conversation even when texting?

PS: I am sorry If this question has already been asked.

Comment: What have your dictionary searches revealed? The answer is likely easily found.

Comment: I found nothing on the subject of using Yo to end a conversation. I found this on urban dictionary "Yo! What the hell do you think you are doing?! Yo, just do your job! YO!, here Yo is being used at the end of the sentence as a declarative or imperative exclamation, but my question is can "Yo" also be used alone to end a conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it at the end of a conversation.  According to Wikipedia:

> Yo is an English slang interjection,[1] commonly associated with American English. It was popularized by the Italian-American community in Philadelphia, Pennsylvania in the 1940s.[2]
>
> ***Although often used as a greeting, yo may come at the end of a sentence, often to direct focus onto a particular individual or group or to gain the attention of another individual or group***. It may specify that a certain statement that had been uttered is more important, or may just be an "attention grabber".